# How can execute SELECT statement on any class

Tags: java, spring, struts2, salesforce

How can execute SELECT statement on any class for Example
I have an class Foo.

```
class Foo
{
Integer id,
String name,
String city
}
```

Now I just want to apply select statement on it. just like

```
Foo fooObject=new Foo();
fooObject =[select id, name, city from Foo limit 1];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to query for an instance of Foo in a collection? Or mapping from a database to instances of Foo?

Comment: Now I updated my query for limit 1 and just want to apply select statement on class not on collection. We knows using ORM we can map any class with Database but i do not want to map class with database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reflection" is the thing that you can use to get values form any object in a programmatic way. But it is not so powerfull like your select statement. Anyway you can build your own framework on top.

```
Class fooClass = Foo.class;
Field[] fields = fooClass.getFields();

for(Field field: fields) 
   Sysout.println("field: " + field.getName() + " = " + field.get.getObject(foo));
```

But reflection is always limited to an single object. As fare as I know reflection does not have a way to obtain all instances of some class.

Comment: I think, we can execute query only on database directly or using ORM and in both of cases we are trying to fetch data from database. 

finally not able execute "select statement on class"

Thank you all of you